# Differential Coefficient using Quotient rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I attempted this Differential Coefficient using the quotient rule. I just got my result back as wrong, with no explanation as to why? Can someone see where I went wrong, and help me rectify it please?

$$y = \frac{4\sin 5x}{5x^4}$$
$$ ( \frac{4\sin(5x)}{5x^4}$$
$$ = \frac{4}{5}\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\sin(5x)}{x^4}$$
Quotient Rule:
$$\frac{f}{g} = \frac{f'xg-g'xf}{g^2}$$
$$= \frac{4}{5} x \frac{ (\sin(5x))x^4-\frac{d}{dx}(x^4)\sin(5x)}{(x^4)}^2$$

$$\frac{4}{5} x \frac{\cos(5x) x 5x^4-4x^3\sin(5x)}{(x^4)^2}$$
$$=\frac{\cos(5x) x 5x^4-4x^3\sin(5x)}{(x^4)^2}$$
$$ \cos (5x) x 5x^4 - 4x^3\sin(5x)$$
$$ = 5\cos (5x) x^3x - 4x^3\sin(5x)$$
$$ = x^3 (5\cos(5x) x -4\sin(5x))$$
$$\frac{x^35\cos(5x)x-4\sin(5x))}{(x^4)^2}$$
$$(x^4)^2$$
$$=x4^4-2$$
$$=x^8$$
$$= \frac{x^3 (5x\cos(5x)-4\sin(5x))}{x^8}$$
$$\frac{x^3}{x^8} = \frac {1}{x^8-3}$$
$$ = \frac{5x cos(5x)-4\sin(5x)}{x^8-3}$$

$$ = \frac{5x\cos(5x)-4\sin(5x)}{x^5}$$
$$= \frac{4}{5} \frac{5x\cos(5x)-4\sin(5x)}{x^5}$$
$$= 4 \frac{5x\cos(5x)-4\sin(5x)}{5x^5}$$

Answer:

$$= 4 \frac{5x\cos(5x)-4\sin(5x)}{5x^5}$$

Comment: Your answer is correct. Please format it properly.

Comment: The final result is correct but the formatting makes it really hard to comprehend the rest. For example the quotient rule is $(\frac{f}{g})' = \frac{f' g - g' f}{g^2}$

Comment: So this is where I went wrong, formatting it. Where have I gone wrong in the format?? Is it to long winded?

Comment: Does my edit answer look correct now?

Comment: Thanks for editing, but still looks broken; what does "$f'xg$" mean? You should always check what the preview shows before pressing "Save Edits".